# How can I get the index of a list item element not "display:none;"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find the index of a list item element that has no attribute `style="display:none;"`.

Here is my basic list:

```html
<ol>
  <li style="display:none;">LI 1</li>
  <li>LI 2</li>
  <li style="display:none;">LI 3</li>
  <li style="display:none;">LI 4</li>
  <li style="display:none;">LI 5</li>
</ol>
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

While you could search for an element without a `style` attribute

```js
const li = document.querySelector('ol li:not([style])');
console.log(li.textContent);
```

```html
<ol>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 1</li>
    <li>LI 2</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 3</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 4</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 5</li>
</ol>
```

If you're going to select elements based on the style display, I'd highly recommend using a class instead:

```js
const li = document.querySelector('ol li:not(.hide)');
console.log(li.textContent);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="hide">LI 1</li>
    <li>LI 2</li>
    <li class="hide">LI 3</li>
    <li class="hide">LI 4</li>
    <li class="hide">LI 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```js
const li = document.querySelector('li:not([style="display:none;"])');
console.log(li.textContent);
```

```html
<ol>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 1</li>
    <li style="display:block;">LI 2</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 3</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 4</li>
    <li style="display:none;">LI 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need